# Unable to get updates from Google Groups

Tags: google-groups

I was subscribed to a Google group at my work place, and I was getting all its messages. Someone sent a spam to that group and instead of blocking the person, I mistakenly spammed the message and unsubscribed from the group. Upon realizing, I am again trying to subscribe to the group, however, I cannot select 'notify me for every new message' because it is not highlighted. See the picture below:

[image]

I tried to again subscribe but did not get any message for a week. Then, I again left the group and when I try to subscribe again, even while trying to apply for membership, I cannot select 'notify me...' because it is not highlighted. 
I have already seen google groups help, e.g., [this link](https://support.google.com/groups/answer/70498?hl=en) but it did not help.

Any help is appreciated, since this group is important for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you made sure the Group's mail is not marked as spam in your Gmail account? Groups is pretty clever and connected to Gmail settings, as it also knows about alternative mail addresses, so I would guess they are able to check this. Maybe you will need to unmark the mail as spam or let Gmail unlearn your spam markings.

Another possibility is that the Google Group got a bounced mail and remembers this for some time. I'm pretty sure that the group admin is able to "unflag" your mail address.

After making sure those things are cleared, you should be able to subscribe again.

Comment: The problem is resolved now. The group settings were not proper apparently, so group admin did something, after which the issue was resolved.

Comment: I find my answer to be a good approach to solve a similar situation so you could still accept it. Or write a better answer and accept it,. So your post can help others in the future